# Cell contains specific text

Tags: excel

> In column A cell A2 contains " **description with CID and cktID and
>   circuit ID and CKT ID and circuit and ck** "
>
> In column B cell B2 contains "**band 10**"
>
> In Column C cell C2 contains "**policy which needed**"
>
> If cell A2 matches "**description**" and "**CID**" or "**cktID**" or
>   "**circuit ID**" or "**CKT ID**" or "**circuit**" or "**ck**" move to cell B2 and check if it matches "**band**" and then move to cell c2 to check whether it matches **policy**.  Finally it need to marked as true.
>
> So need to validate in three different cells with specific words on
>   the three different columns. Need to know the count of A2/B2 match,
>   A2/C2 match and A2/B2/C2.

I dont know about excel much, so need help on this.

Thanks !!!

Comment: you would like to validate a text value or a numerical value? .. any sample data/screenshoot will help. | Note : the only automated validation function in excel I know is at Data > Data Validation. Anything other than that, need a little more effort.

Comment: need to validate on text values. I am unable to send data/screen shot due to some block on my company laptop. i am trying my end, however not getting results. if any excel experts are there, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pseudo formula you could use to help get your desired result.

```
=IF(A1 = "A", IF(B1= "B", IF(C1=  "C", "True")))
```